# Is it feasible to create custom CollectionViewLayout where spacing between individual cell can specifically control

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to build a honeycomb using UiCollectionView . I have used https://github.com/cyrilchandelier/CCHexagonFlowLayout component for creating the basic structure of my view.

[image: Before tapped to any cell]

According to the requirement when any cell is tapped the adjacent  cells should move out distance x from the tapped cell, with animation .

I have create two collectionViewLayout with different spacing value and changing it at `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method

Here is my code …

```
#import "HoneycombViewController.h"


@interface HoneycombViewController ()
// Collection view
@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property(nonatomic,strong)  CCHexagonFlowLayout *layout;

@property(nonatomic,strong)  CCHexagonFlowLayout *largeLayout;

@property(nonatomic) CGFloat minimumItemSpacingFactor;
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat minimumLineSpacingFactor ;
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat layoutGapFactor ;

@end

@implementation A3HoneycombViewController
@synthesize minimumLineSpacingFactor,minimumItemSpacingFactor,layoutGapFactor;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.minimumItemSpacingFactor = 10.0f;
    self.minimumLineSpacingFactor = 10.0f;
    self.layoutGapFactor = 10.0f;

    // Build layout
    self.layout = [[CCHexagonFlowLayout alloc] init];
    self.layout.delegate = self;
     //layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    self.layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    self.layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = -30.0f;
    self.layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0f;
    self.layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0f, 15.0f, 20.0f, 15.0f);
    self.layout.itemSize = RootCell_SIZE;

    //layout.headerReferenceSize = HeaderView_SIZE(layout.scrollDirection);
    //layout.footerReferenceSize = FooterView_SIZE(layout.scrollDirection);

    self.layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,50) ;
    self.layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,50) ;
    self.layout.gap = 76.0f;

    //create large layout
    self.largeLayout = [[CCHexagonFlowLayout alloc] init];
    self.largeLayout.delegate = self;
    self.largeLayout.scrollDirection = self.layout.scrollDirection;
    self.largeLayout.minimumLineSpacing = self.layout.minimumLineSpacing+self.minimumLineSpacingFactor;
    self.largeLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = self.layout.minimumInteritemSpacing+self.minimumItemSpacingFactor;
    self.largeLayout.itemSize =  self.layout.itemSize;
    self.largeLayout.sectionInset = self.layout.sectionInset;
    self.largeLayout.headerReferenceSize =self.layout.headerReferenceSize;
    self.largeLayout.footerReferenceSize =  self.layout.footerReferenceSize;
    self.largeLayout.gap = self.layout.gap + self.layoutGapFactor;



    // Build collection view
    _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:self.layout];
    _collectionView.dataSource = self;
    _collectionView.delegate = self;
    _collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Register cell and views
    [_collectionView registerNib:[RootCell cellNib] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:RootCell_ID];
    [_collectionView registerNib:[HeaderView viewNib] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:HeaderView_ID];
    [_collectionView registerNib:[FooterView viewNib] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:FooterView_ID];

    // Add to view
    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];

    // Reload data
    [_collectionView reloadData];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionDataSource methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            return 10;

        default:
            return 10;
    }
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RootCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:RootCell_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell configureWithInt:indexPath.item];

    return cell;
}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
           viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                                 atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Section header
    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader])
        return [_collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind
                                                   withReuseIdentifier:HeaderView_ID
                                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Section footer
    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter])
        return [_collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind
                                                   withReuseIdentifier:FooterView_ID
                                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return nil;
}
-(CGSize)collectionViewContentSize { //Workaround
    CGSize superSize = [self.layout collectionViewContentSize];
    CGRect frame = self.collectionView.frame;
    return CGSizeMake(fmaxf(superSize.width, CGRectGetWidth(frame)), fmaxf(superSize.height, CGRectGetHeight(frame)));
}
//
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     UICollectionViewLayout *toLayout = self.layout == self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout ? self.largeLayout : self.layout;
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:toLayout animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"animation end ");
    }];



}
```

[image: After tabbing to hexagon 1]

In the screenshot2 I have tapped in cell 1 now adjacent cells like 0 ,5,6,7,2 moved correctly  as marked in green but other cells also moved marked in red .

As per this code all cell layout is changed  but I want only my tabbed cell should be stick to its position and change its cell spacing show that it seems like its adjacent cells are move away at distance x also other cells  in between space should remain with older value. Is it feasible to create custom `CollectionViewLayout` where spacing between individual cell can specifically control ? Also how we can use different `CollectionViewLayout`  for different cells?

Comment: howd this end up working out for you?

Comment: Basically when user tapped on a cell I want to create a circular space surrounded on the selected cell. Then I will add some subviews on that free space related with tapped cell. Similarly if he tap on any other cell then current cell subviews will be removed and other surrounded cell will come close to it with animation , then the new tapped cell will be animated similar fashion .